# What's purpose to forbid delegate call in UniswapV3

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I'm studying Uniswap V3 and have noticed that `UniswapV3Pool` uses `NoDeletageCall` contract, which forbid executes Uniswap's code with another storage.

My question here: what's the purpose of such restriction? Because from my point of view this restriction is useless and nothing can be happened with base contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment from the [pull request](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/pull/327) implementing this feature.

> Prevents circumventing the license, GPL or otherwise